# Upload csv file in Reatjs frontend and send it back to backend server

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I want to upload csv file in Reatjs frontend and send it back to the backend server(Spring Rest API).

Comment: After storing the selected file (in the state), we are now required to send it to a server

Comment: would recommend react-uploady. (Only partly because I wrote it)

Comment: Please provide with the methods that you have tried to solve it ,  don't be like `yeah ,this is my issue solve it`. Explain what you tried and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) has lot of things that solve this issue. Checkout [`react-upload-file`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-upload-file)

Answer (score -1):

you could simply make a post http request with the file appended in a form data object, like this using axios (or any other lib you prefer)

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", yourStateFile);
 axios.post('yourUrl', formData, {
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
})
```

Comment: const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);
    console.log(data);

    var DATA_USER = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    console.log(this.state);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8002/api/csv/upload", data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${DATA_USER.accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })

Comment: there is some issue with header in frontend code, its not able to recognized CSV file ,so at backend throwing error not a csv file !! though same file I am able to upload via postman

Answer (score -2):

```
To upload a CSV file in a React.js frontend and send it back to a backend server, you can follow these steps:

 1. Set up the React.js project: Create a new React.js project or use an
    existing one.
    
 2. Create a file upload component: In your React component, create a
    form with an input field of type "file" to allow users to select the
    CSV file.
 

**jsx**
-------

 
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function FileUploadComponent() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleFileUpload = () => {
    if (selectedFile) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', selectedFile);

      // Send the formData to the backend server
      // You can use Axios, Fetch API, or any other HTTP library to send the request
      // Example using Axios:
      // axios.post('/api/upload', formData)
      //   .then(response => {
      //     // Handle the response from the server
      //   })
      //   .catch(error => {
      //     // Handle any errors
      //   });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileUploadComponent;
 

Handle
======

    
Handle the file upload on the backend server: In your backend server code (e.g., using Node.js with Express), create a route to handle the file upload. Use a middleware to handle the file upload and save the file on the server or process it as required.

javascript/Node
===============

const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // Handle the uploaded file
  const file = req.file;

  // Process the file as needed (e.g., save to a database, parse the CSV, etc.)

  // Send a response back to the client
  res.send('File uploaded successfully');
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

Make sure to install the necessary dependencies, such as axios for the frontend and express and multer for the backend, using a package manager like npm or yarn.

With these steps, you can create a file upload component in your React.js frontend, send the selected CSV file to the backend server, and handle the file upload on the server side.
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).